# understanding Makefiles

Tags: makefile

I have the following make file:

```
CC = gcc
CCDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-multichar
COMPONENTHEADER = Q_OBJECT 
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/Inventor/annex -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/share/qt3/include  
CXX = g++
CXXCPP = g++ -E
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -fno-exceptions -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-multichar -Woverloaded-    virtual
CYGPATH_W = echo
GUI = QT
Gui = Qt
INCLUDES = 
LIBS = -lSoQt -lqt-mt -lXmu -lXi -lCoin -lGL -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -ldl -lpthread -lm -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux 
OBJS = MathTools.o PointCloud.o ExtractFeatures.o Tile.o Shape.o RoadDynamic.o
SRCS = MathTools.cpp PointCloud.cpp ExtractFeatures.cpp Tile.cpp Shape.cpp RoadDynamic.cpp main.cpp 
HDRS =  constants.h Shape.h MathTools.h PointCloud.h ExtractFeatures.h Tile.h RoadDynamic.h
WIDGET = QWidget *

all: main


main: main.o ${OBJS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -o $@ main.o ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

.c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $<

depend: 
    makedepend ${SRCS}

clean:
    rm *.o core *~

tar:
    tar cf code.tar  Makefile *.c *.h testfile1

print:
    more Makefile $(HDRS) $(SRCS) | enscript -2r -p listing.ps
```

I am wondering why when I run make the output is

```
g++ -g -O2 -fno-exceptions -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-multichar -Woverloaded-virtual -I/usr/include/Inventor/annex -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/share/qt4/include    -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

instead of:

```
gcc -g -O2 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-multichar ...
```

it seems the cxx variables are overriding the cc variables.  Why is that?

also what does the "include =" do in this case? It doesn't seem to be set to anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your object files are apparently built from .cpp files.  You have no explicit rule for building .o files from .cpp files, so Make uses the [implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`.

Comment: Thank you Oli.  How about the INCLUDES variable.  What is that being set to?

Comment: @user1461142: It's being set to nothing (i.e. an empty string).